# PHP Getting a reference through a constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I am wondering if it is possible while using the keyword 'new' to return a reference to an existing object instead of a new object. And if not, what would be the best way to avoid co-existence of objects with the same parameters?

I have a class with arguments on the constructor. If I am using arguments similar to the ones of an existing instance, I'd like my new object to be a reference to the existing one. Is it possible? I understand it is different than a singleton as in this case we can have several instances of the same class, but not several instances using the same parameters.

```
class myClass{
 public $signature; /* Unique signature for the connection */
 public static $instances = array(); /* Array of references to connection */
 private static function singleton($cfg,$inst){
   $signature = sha1(serialize($cfg));
   foreach ( self::$instances as $obj )
   {
     if ( $obj->signature == $signature )
       return $obj;
   }
   array_push(self::$instances,$inst);
   return true;
 }
 function __construct($myParam){
   if ( is_object(self::singleton($myParam,$this) )
     // Here I'd like $this to become the ref of my existing object
   else
   {
     $this->signature = $myParam;
     // I construct my new object
   }
 }
}
$e1 = new myClass(1);
$e2 = new myClass(2);
$e3 = new myClass(1); // $e3 should be a reference to $e1
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for the factory pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First a few facts:**

- The constructor can never return a value.
- $this cannot be reassigned (it could in PHP 4 but wasn't intended, and was undocumented)

**Conclusion:**

- Use factory methods or delegation.*

* There is a slight difference between the two, and that is that using delegation $a!=$b, but using factory methods $a === $b (see below)

**Delegation example:**

```
// Declare the delegate that will be wrapped by DelegationClass
// * Only public methods/properties will be accessible
class MyClass {
    public $a;
    public function a($a) {
        echo "This is a(\$a=$a)\n";
    }
}

class MyDelegationClass {
    static protected $_delegation = 'MyClass'; // define the delegate
    static protected $_i = array(); // instances
    protected $_l = null; // delegation link
    public function __construct($n) {
       if (!array_key_exists($n,self::$_i)) {
           // ensures that the instance is always created
           self::$_i[$n] = new self::$_delegation; 
        }
        $this->_l = self::$_i[$n]; // link to delegate
    }
    public function __get($v) {
        return $this->_l->$v; // get property from delegate link
    }
    public function __set($k,$v) {
        return $this->_l->$k = $v; // set property on delegate link
    }
    public function __call($f,$p) {
        // call method on delegate link
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->_l,$f),$p); 
    }
}
// $a != $b, but $a->a === $b->a
$a = new MyDelegationClass(1);
$b = new MyDelegationClass(1);
```

**Factory class example:**

```
class MyFactoryClass {
    static protected $_i = array(); // instances
    public static function newMyClass($n) {
       if (!array_key_exists($n,self::$_i)) {
           // ensures that the instance is always created
           self::$_i[$n] = new MyClass; 
        }
        return self::$_i[$n]; // return instance
    }
}
// $a === $b
$a = MyFactoryClass::newMyClass(1);
$b = MyFactoryClass::newMyClass(1);
```

Comment: So if I understood well, I can't use 'new' in that case, I need to use a static function, right? What if I put the part of the object I don't want to recreate in a property? Can't I then access the reference to the existing object from this property?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you can return the same object from the factory method, or you can contain the object and use delegation. With delegation you can use the new keyword.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! The delegation seems to be what I meant in my babbling by "referencing the object in a property". And if I use delegation my __construct function should always return a new object, but with either the main object embedded or referenced, right? (sorry again for the babbling)

Comment: First, construct implicitly returns a reference to the new object, you should not return anything as it will not have any effect. To implement methods, you need to overload __call()

Comment: Ok, I updated my example a bit. You probably want to separate the classes to get an intuitive interface to class methods, otherwise it will be a mess. The example just in it's (one of it's) simplest forms.

Comment: I see this: self::$_i[$n] = new self::$_delegation; in the __construct of your delegation example. I thought a static property couldn't be changed from a non static function. I gonna check this out. Thanks for the great help, I'm almost done.

Comment: It's the other way round, a non static property cannot be changed within a static method. Please mark my answer as accepted if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Seems to work fine. You forgot the return for the function __call, I'll edit it

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it just be easier to directly store the object references in your `instances` var?

```
if (!isset(self::$instances[$myparam])) {
    self::$instances[$myParam] = ... new object here ...;
} else
    return &self::$instances[$myParam];
}
```

Just guessing, but it seems that storing your simple integer parameter as an array key to the instances cache would be "cheaper" than storing an sha1 signature of a serialized structure that could potentially NOT be the same even if the object has the same initial parameter.

Comment: My simple integer is just for the example. But it's a good idea to put the signature as index for $instances