# Can you handle the error thrown when trying to instantiate a singleton using new?

Tags: php

What I would like to do on this error is to just return the already instantiated singleton. What I need is for the 'new' keyword to do this. The reason why is If some noob tries to access my script and initiate the singleton class using `new`. I also would like the noob's script to continue and not die.
Is there a way to implement this?

Comment: As constructors can't return values the answer is no afaik. The only thing u could do is make the constructor private. This way no instances can be initiated outside the class

Comment: It's really too bad that you can't do this... It be nice

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but it is not possible in PHP language. Constructor cannot return values, the only way to implement singleton safely is to make constructor private.

However there are few tricks to build something "similar" trough delegation and factory patterns.

Here is the link to the post:
[PHP Getting a reference through a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622605/php-getting-a-reference-through-a-constructor)